# PineScript setting qty as current cash balance on the strategy (wundertraiding)

Tags: bots, pine-script, pine-script-v5

The goal is to send this format to wundertrading:

```
{
 "code":"{{strategy.order.comment}}",
 "qty": {{strategy.order.contracts}}
}
```

Contracts have to have cache balance as value (or any other strategy property that holds that value)

I've tried to to set qty param on my strategy to current balance but it changes the backtested results dramatically. Therefore, it won't produce alerts that would normally be triggered.

Default conf:
`strategy("xxxxx", overlay=true, initial_capital=5320, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100, calc_on_every_tick = false, commission_value=0.1)`

```
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment = commentLong)
```

With cache position:

`strategy("xxxxx", overlay=true, initial_capital=5320, default_qty_type=strategy.cash,  calc_on_every_tick = false, commission_value=0.1)`

```
positionSizeDollars = strategy.position_size * strategy.position_avg_price
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment = commentLong, qty: positionSizeDollars)
```

Thanks in advance.